# Sheetnode Formulas

Tags: drupal-7, phpexcel

I am currently using a module named 'Sheetnode' for Drupal 7. It's a great module, however it seems that the excel ROUNDUP function is not working or supported. The excel data I import (through PHPEXCEL) is in .xlsx format containing multiple calculations. However some formulas are incorrect causing wrong totals and rounding up values. All figures on the spreadsheet must be precise. Has anyone had experience with this module? And possible ways around this?

Many thanks

Comment: I'm not familiar with Sheetnode, but I do know a bit about PHPExcel. Please provide some examples of formula calculations that are not working (with arguments and expected/actual results) and I may be able to help.

Comment: Hi Mark, apologies for the delayed reply. An example would be something like =SUM(D60*F60) where on the actual spreadsheet the result is 294 but online the result is 294.232123213 and the formulas are exactly the same. Numbers are also being rounded up so 134 on the spreadsheet will become 135 when imported and and vice versa. It's difficult to explain precisely, and I'm new to using PHPexcel, It would be nice to have a functional workbook! Many thanks